# Sort an array by specific values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, search

Here is the scenario, I have a database and I need data that is different from four tables to display in a list. I was having trouble getting the queries to join in a way that would give the results that I needed in the right order and format so I did a bunch of queries and pushed the results to and array. So now I have this array and it works great so far.

To visualize this I have the data listed in table and I need to sort the table based on the heading.

What I need to do next is some how sort the array by a specific value.

For example I have the array that contains a value “type” I want to search the array for the specific “types” and then sort the array based on that. So if the “type” column contains items such as “file” , “link” or “quiz” it would sort alphabetically.

Is this possible? Or should I be thinking of this in a different way?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: begin by posting code! with sample data, such as your tables structures

Comment: `SELECT column from table WHERE column='something' ORDER BY value` - or even `LIKE`

Comment: Another option is `in_array()` and `ksort()`, `sort()`, `rsort()` etc. - pretty broad though.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you'll probably have better results by letting the database do the work, rather than post-processing it in PHP.

As the other folks are saying, some more specifics and code examples would allow us to provide better help, but based on what you've said:

To limit your query results to a specific type, you would add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT [whatever columns] FROM table_name WHERE type = 'file'
```

If you want to select multiple types at the same time:

```
SELECT [whatever columns] FROM table_name WHERE type IN ('file', 'link', 'quiz')
```

If you want to order them alphabetically by type:

```
SELECT [whatever columns] FROM table_name WHERE type IN ('file', 'link', 'quiz') ORDER BY type ASC
```